# Can you get normal Figure captions for Graphviz (digraph) graphs with Sphinx python document generator?

Tags: python-sphinx, graphviz, caption

Can you use Figure captions for graphs created by Graphviz (digraph) with Sphinx?  I would like to use the same numbering and style of captions for my Graphviz graphs as a I do for all Figures.

For example, if I try putting this into the restructured text document used by Sphinx:

```
.. digraph:: foo

   "bar" -> "baz";

.. _figure_digraph:

   **Fig. X label at start of Figure label is missing**
```

Then I get a Figure where the Fig. X at the beginning of the Figure caption is missing.

[image]

Comment: Did you try putting `.. _figure_digraph:` before the `digraph` directive?

Comment: Putting `.. _figure_digraph: ` before the `digraph` directive has the same result.